# Generate all HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am making a Web application, and I'm wondering how far I should take JavaScript use.

It's a simple application that could be made in one page, and thus appear "app-like" and quickly responsive (using direct DOM manipulation combined with AJAX).

I see three general ways I can take this:

- A) Generate all HTML on the server, do minor DOM manipulation in JavaScript, use AJAX to post smaller changes to the server, and reload the page for larger changes.
- B) Generate all HTML on the server, but reload the page less, and instead use more AJAX to have the server return ready-prepared HTML to insert into various .
- C) Generate all HTML in JavaScript, and have the server return nothing but JSON objects with data to insert into the HTML.

The reason I'm curious about option C, is that it would give an interesting MVC feel to things. The server does the Model, and the client does the View.

Please note that clients lacking JavaScript is not an issue, and I would use a JavaScript framework to ensure browser compatibility.

Does anyone have positive experiences with this that smoothened the development process? Is this maybe an established method that has a specific name, even?

Comment: REST API and rendering views in the client is common structure for SPAs nowadays. I would go with C.

Comment: C is like javascript templating.

Comment: I now build HTML apps with JavaScript, having moved away from PHP-generated HTML. A friend who works for Google predictably persuaded me that the preferable way is to download a fixed HTML file (which can be cached) and then use AJAX/JavaScript to build from there. Once the user is logged in, the page never reloads.

Comment: Have you considered using a JS framework like Angular, Ember or Backbone for this single page app? DOM manipulation would be quite easy and you can also use ajax wherever needed.

Comment: Random things I've seen around the blogosphere however suggest that using approach C does make loading times and general performance worse, mostly on mobile clients that don't really handle heavy Javascript nearly as well as desktops. So there's that to consider. Serving as much **static** HTML as possible and then using progressive enhancement techniques for personalisation will be fastest, if a lot of work. (Which is kind of a mixture of all the approaches you mention.)

Comment: Personally I heavily use frameworks that render HTML snippets on the server but that's because the architecture of the line-of-business apps involves a traditional server-side framework anyway. The choice is motivated mostly by not wanting to use two tools for the same job, and having more familiarity with the server-side tools. Client-side rendering and data-binding is mostly Knockout to add to the server-side stuff, not replace it.

Comment: +1 to option C, I did just that for my present company's internal applications.

Answer (score 0):

Our product's webclient is made entirely by the option C. However, I can't say much about the benefits, since in our case it started as a necessity: a) it was started back in days when even the oldest JS frameworks were doing their baby steps; b) the project had a lot of programmers experienced in Java/OOP in general, but who felt uneasy with the declarative-ness of html.

So, what was done back then -- is a "OO-JS" framework, which used all the OO-hacks available to Javascript (e.g. inheritance hack, fake encapsulation, and so on) to make an API which "felt" mostly like Java coding -- you had a hierarchy of objects, you could write some functional-style code that modified the page's html around. All this without even touching the html itself. Back in the day it was pretty cool, now it's pretty normal.

And so we use this home-brewed framework to this day (the cost of migrating to 3rd-party frameworks is way too high now), and it's still functions pretty much the same way it was originally intended. Our pages are nothing than a bunch of JS imports (also i18n'ed messages, various text constants, etc) plus a function that fires the entire process upon `DOMContentLoaded` event. After that -- it's purely Javascript to do the rest of the job.

Now, our product uses a *very* rich UI driven by lots of ajax calls, and I can't honestly recommend using approach C in any other case -- more simpler UIs can be implemented *far* easier by taking either A or B approach. But I'm sure you understand that quite well.

Comment: PS: Some pics of the fairly recently-made parts of our webclient (it's highly modular, so it's used across different corporate products, but fresh screenshots are rare to come by): http://www.rocketsoftware.com/products/rocket-mainstar-mxi-zos/screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Some template systems support both server side and client side. Once written, a template page can be used on both side.

By detecting whether a HTTP request is AJAX or old style, the server side could send JSON string (as the template's data map) back instead of rendered HTML content. They enable you switch between the three plans smoothly.

One of such template system comparison could be found at http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more

Answer (score 0):

For a few years now we are using approach C in almost all our web applications. This has some benefits especially when your system is under heavy load. In our architecture there is a cluster of web servers delivering the static content (.html, .js, .css, .png, etc. files) while the dynamic requests are forwarded to another cluster of application servers (REST requests based on URL patterns). Typically these app servers are the bottleneck with all the business logic and communication to databases or other backend systems. So generating the HTML on the many clients takes the load of building a server page away from your few app servers. Additionally you are reducing traffic since the JSON objects are usually much smaller than the entire HTML markup outweighing the extra JavaScript code that has to be transferred once (it can be cached by the browser anyway).

Now in your .html file you still have the option to do the static markup with tags or start with an empty `<body/>` and create the entire DOM tree in JavaScript which is my favourite way since I don't like to mix the two approaches.

Another consideration is whether you want to be found by search engines or not. They won't index your dynamically created HTML so in this scenario a server page might make sense.